# removing duplicates from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to remove duplicate objects from an arraylist 
see code below:

```
ArrayList<Customer> customers=new ArrayList<Customer>();

    for(int i=0;i<accounts.size();i++){
        customers.add(accounts.get(i).getCustomer());
    }

    for(int i=0;i<customers.size();i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<customers.size();j++){
            if(customers.get(i).getSocialSecurityNo().compareTo(customers.get(j).getSocialSecurityNo())==0){
                if(customers.get(i).getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(customers.get(j).getLastName())==0){
                    if(customers.get(i).getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(customers.get(j).getFirstName())==0){
                        customers.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    }
```

However, it seems that the last object in the list is not being processed. Perhaps someone can pinpoint the error

Comment: Insert it into a Set

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435156/java-removing-duplicates-in-an-arraylist

Comment: If you follow tylermac's suggestions (which is a good one).  Make sure to override the equals() and hashCode() methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `j--;` after removing an item.  That will reindex for you and solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The basic flaw is that since the ListArray is mutable, once you remove one element your indexes have to be readjusted.

```
if(customers.get(i).getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(customers.get(j).getFirstName())==0){
       customers.remove(j--);
}
```

also try subtracting one from your i loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<customers.size()-1;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<customers.size();j++){
```

Comment: That's where iterators come into play.

Comment: Yeah, iterators are always better!

Comment: @Voo: Iterators don't really help here, you will get ConcurrentModificationExceptions here on a stock ArrayList.

Comment: @Paulo Well you can get it actually work with an Iterator, but it doesn't look any better. So yeah not that great.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList list) {
            HashSet set = new HashSet(list);
            list.clear();
            list.addAll(set);
    }
```

override equals and hashcode appropriatley

Comment: You should change the method signature to `removeDuplicates(Collection list)` (program to the interface and not a concrete class).

Comment: So I guess I can't use your method with a `LinkedList` or any other non-ArrayList collection. You'll just have to copy-paste the method and accept another class type.

Comment: `LinkedList` is one of the many collection in the Java collections framework. Take a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html and look under "All Known Implementing Classes" for the various `Collection` implementations.

Comment: @Steve I'm not sure what that has to do with anything.

Comment: @nsfyn55 Java language specification are now driven by Oracle, so by using java, you are at their mercy...

Answer (score 1):

custormers = new ArrayList(new HashSet(customers))

ensure the equals and hashmethod are correctly implemented

Answer (score 1):

The code below worked for me. Give it a try. You can manipulate the compare method to suit your taste

`ArrayList customers = .....;

         Set customerlist = new TreeSet(new Comparator(){`

```
        @Override
        public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
            return c1.getSocialSecurityNo().compareTo(c2.getSocialSecurityNo());
        }            
    });
    customerlist.addAll(customers);
    customers.clear();
    customers.addAll(customerlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your `int j=i+1` that causes trouble. You need to test with the last value of the customers list for each iteration.

Comment: The j+1 just makes sure that each item is compared with itself.

Answer (score 0):

Before you add them to the list in the above loop, why don't you check

```
if(!cutomers.contains(accounts.get(i).getCustomer())
{
//add them if it doesn't contain
}
```

It should save you from doing the second loop

Edit: Need to override the [equals](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2006/04/27/HowTo_Override_equals_and_hashCode_Part1.aspx) method.

Comment: @RMT, I once suggested this and was the focus of a lot of negativity. :)

Comment: @mre that is true, its not the greatest thing to use, I think it should be better then having a 2nd and 3rd loop below.(just my opinion:) )

Comment: There are a lot of better ways to do the problem, but that doesn't answer his/her question.  What is wrong with his/her algorithm?

Comment: @RMT I tried to do that and it doesn't seem to work for(int i=0;i<accounts.size();i++){ if (!customers.contains(accounts.get(i).getCustomer())){ customers.add(accounts.get(i).getCustomer()); } }

Comment: @trs what i forget to metion you got to override the Equals method. basically a customer is equal when (from what i can tell) everything you have in your if statements.

Comment: @RMT how do you override the equals method?

Comment: Ill post the link to the documentation in my answer

Comment: @trs let me know if you need anymore help

Answer (score 0):

So, about doing this right:

Your Customer objects should have an [equals()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [hashCode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method, which do the comparison. (Or you simply would have only one Customer object for each customer, which would mean your data model would have to be adjusted. Then the default hashCode/equals would do.)

If you have this, you can replace your three nested ifs with one:

```
    if(customers.get(i).equals(customers.get(j)) {
       customers.remove(j);
    }
```

This would not yet solve your problem, but make it easier to have a clearer look on it. If
you look at which objects are compared to which others, you will see that after each removal
of an object from the list, the next one has the same index as the one which you just removed,
and you will not compare the current object to it. As said, `j--` after the removal will solve this.

A more performant solution would be using a Set (which is guaranteed not to contain duplicates).
In your case, a `HashSet<Customer>` or `LinkedHashSet<Customer>` (if you care about the order)
will do fine.

Then your whole code comes down to this:

```
Set<Customer> customerSet = new HashSet<Customer>();

for(Account acc : accounts){
    customerSet.add(acc.getCustomer());
}
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>(customerSet);
```

If you don't really need a list (i.e. indexed access), ommit the last line and simply
use the set instead.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to use Sets, as others have mentioned.  Another approach would be to use Java's version of the foreach, instead of using indexes.  A general approach:

```
public static ArrayList removeDuplicates(ArrayList origList) {
    ArrayList newList = new ArrayList();
    for (Object m : origList) {
        if (!newList.contains(m)) {
            newList.add(m);
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```

In testing, I just used Strings; I'd recommend inserting Customer into the code where appropriate for type safety.